# How to debug a bootstrap + dhtmlxgrid CSS conflict

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, dhtmlx

I have a Rails 4.2 app with JQuery, Bootstrap and dhtmlx.

Now if I create a [dhtmlXGrid](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/) on a page, the grid appears.

But if I change the column size with the mouse, the entire grid size decreases. (strange bug)

If I remove the class gridbox from the #gridbox div (after page loading with chrome developper Tools) the bug disappears but the style also (of course!).

If I remove the bootstrap css the grid work properly (but of course bootstrap navbar not!)

How to debug this behavior?

I search the gridbox class in bootstrap but it does'nt exists. So how to know what is causing the grid to be resized?

I have a test zip with an example just open the html.html file:

[dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/71msq6vnsl27trk/dhtmlxBootstrapConflict.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here : [dhtmlx forum](http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34134)

just add some css in application.css (or application.css.scss)

```
div.gridbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

There is another problem : the horizontal scroll bar is always displayed